# QTP Using if statement for Run Time Object

Tags: if-statement, qtp, hp-uft

How can I set up the if statement so that QTP will display Passed or Failed if conditions met. Currently I have the properties of a valid coupon and invalid coupon. Each will display a different message on the website. Please see the code below:

```
Set objBrowser = Browser("name:=.*Chico's")
Set objPage = objBrowser.Page("title:=.*Chico's")

Dim x
x=datatable.GetSheet("Global").GetRowCount

'-----for loop---------
For i = 1 To x Step 1

Datatable.SetCurrentRow(i)

objPage.WebEdit("html tag:=INPUT","html id:=claimCodeField","name:=claimCodeField").Set datatable ("Coupon_code", GlobalSheet)
wait 2
objPage.Image("name:=CouponFormHandler","html tag:=INPUT","image type:=Image Button","file name:=btn_apply\.gif").Click                                                        
wait 2

objBrowser.Sync

Dim Coupon, Couponerror

    xlCoupondescription=dataTable ("Coupon_description", GlobalSheet)

    xlInvalid=dataTable("Invalid_coupon", GlobalSheet)

'----Coupon----

    Coupon=objPage.WebElement("class:=sb-promo-msg","html tag:=SPAN","html id:=","Index:=1").GetROProperty("outertext") 

'----Coupon Error msg-----  
    Couponerror=objPage.WebElement("class:=sb-error-message","html tag:=DIV","html id:=").GetROProperty("outertext")


'----if statement---------


    If (Trim(Coupon) = Trim(xlCoupondescription))  Then

            datatable.value("Actual_results", GlobalSheet)="Passed"

        If (Trim(Coupon) = Trim(Couponerror)) Then

        datatable.value("Actual_results", GlobalSheet)="Failed"
        End If 
        End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Reporter.ReportEvent` method when you want to report custom pass/fail conditions.